# Динамика полей HTML-формы в зависимости от выбора их значений на Django

Tags: django, формы

**Есть простая задача для Django - динамически вывести к заполнению 3 поля HTML-формы.**

- 1-е поле выводится всегда и содержит select-набор значений из
  некоторого списка.
- 2-е поле выводится всегда и содержит select-набор значений из другого
  списка, соответствующего выбору значения в 1-м поле.
- 3-е поле необходимо только в некоторых случаях в зависимости от
  выбранного значения 2-го поля.

Пробую решить задачу с помощью словаря, где ключи - это элементы для 1-го поля, а значения ключей - набор для 2-го поля.

Вывод 3-го поля зависит от наличия ненулевых элементов в списке значений по каждому ключу. Если значение `None`, то 3-е поле не выводится, иначе поле выводится, а ненулевое значение является подсказкой внутри 3-го поля.

3-е поле - простое текстовое (не select).

**Словарь зависимостей для списков значений полей:**

```py
dict = {
        'Лор': (('Вазотомия', None), 
                ('Тонзилэктомия', None), 
                ('Оперативное лечение', None)),

        'Травматология'): (('Удаление МОС', '... Где устанавливался МОС'),
                           ('Артроскопия', '...Где консультировался пациент'),                            
                           ('Удаление кисты Бейкера', '...Где консультировался пациент'), 
                           ('Другие', None)),
}
```

Как мы видим, для ключа `'Лор'` 3-е поле не требуется ни по одному из элементов - значений 2-го поля.

Если в 1-м поле выбрана `'Травматология'`, то во 2-м поле будет список из четырёх значений, первые три из которых требуют вывода 3-го поля формы. Например, во 2-м поле выбрано `'Удаление МОС'`, то 3-е поле выведется с подсказкой `'... Где устанавливался МОС'`.

Порекомендуйте, плиз, боле-менее подходящее решение данного вопроса. Конечно, предпочтительно применить сам Django в чистом виде, однако, не исключается и JS либо Ajax.

Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Насколько я знаю, у джанго нет такого решения из коробки. Так что js

Comment: Если в джанго-стиле, то можно в атрибуте виджета указать `attrs={'onchange':'ваш_js_код'}`, где ваш_js_код будет делать запрос или выборку из заранее подготовленного словаря в зависимости от выбранного значения в select,  и генерировать новый select с нужными значениями на основе этой выборки (ответа на запрос)

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю сделать это решение на Jquery, если тебя это заинтересует, могу помочь.
Чтобы примерно понимал, то я предлагаю сделать просто HTML верстку и по выбранному значению в  выбирать соответствующие значения в другом  и так далее.

Comment: ОК, технология принципиального решения мне понятна. Примерный код на JS тоже обозначился внутри чистого HTML. Сейчас я рассматриваю чуть усложнённый вариант, как универсальный, и в моём случае обязательный - добраться с помощью Ajax'а до словаря со значениями полей, который определён внутри модели. Конечно, мне интересно взглянуть на предложенное решение. Заранее благодарен за любое участие в этом вопросе, тем более, что здесь напрашивается некий стандартизированный подход, который будет полезен не только мне..